# How to pass array in controller class

Tags: javascript, java, object-literal

In my array like this:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "hh",
            "hh",
            "jk",
            "ggh",
            "hvh",
            null
        ],
        [
            "dd",
            "gg",
            null,
            "nn",
            "rr",
            "jj"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I want to pass above array data in controller class:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '/MobitelProgressTool/wifi_mane',
                        data: JSON.stringify(list),
                        type: 'POST', //<== not 'GET',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        error: function () {
                            console.log("error");
                        },
                        success: function (arr) {
                            console.log(arr.testArray);
                            var testArray = arr.testArray;
                            $.each(function (i, e) {
                                document.writeln(e);
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

the controller class is...

```
RequestMapping(value = {"/wifi_mane"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody// <== this annotation will bind Arr class and convert to json response.
    public Arr addAnotherAppointment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody Arr arr, Model model, BindingResult errors) {
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^" + arr.getTestArray());
        return arr;
    }
```

My array class is:

```
public class Arr {
    private List<String> testArray;

    /**
     * @return the testArray
     */
    public List<String> getTestArray() {
        return testArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param testArray the testArray to set
     */
    public void setTestArray(List<String> testArray) {
        this.testArray = testArray;
    }
```

but I cannot pass array data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, I think this should work :

```
public class Arr {
  private List<String> keys;
  private List<List<String>> data;

  //... getters and setters
}
```